# How to find all nodes within a range of weighted edges with gremlin?

Tags: graph, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to get a list of shortest paths from a given start node to all nodes that are within a given range. Each edge is weighted and I am trying to use the sum of these weights as the range, rather than the number of steps.

The following works for limiting steps, but I'm not sure how to aggregate and limit path edge weights or return paths properly.

```
g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.loops < 3}{true}.dedup
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this Tinkerpop 2 or 3?

Comment: 2. Haven't moved to 3 yet, but it's an option if required.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with 2 because loop is breadth-first so you either need separate accumulators for each path or a way to sum the entire path within the loop closure. The latter would be much better. I understand Tinkerpop 3 has (or was going to have) depth-first as an option but I have tried it yet, but it seems like a variable or an array of variables could be added to as the depth increases and reset as it ascends.

Comment: I think the loop has a  ```it.path``` property, could I check this in the condition? Something like ```sum(it.path.edges.length) < THRESHOLD && !path.isLoop``` ?

Comment: Tried ```g.V[0].outE.inV.loop(2){it.loops < 3 && it.path.transform{[it.findAll{it instanceof Edge}.sum{it.weight}, it]}}{true}.enablePath().dedup.path``` 

and getting a

 ```lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: arraylist.transform()``` error. Not sure I'm understanding what it.path is.

Comment: Moved to Tinkerpop 3 and am attempting to use sack steps - but can't seem to compare sack inside until like so ```g.withSack(0.0f).V(4).until(sack()>0.3f).emit().repeat(outE().sack(sum,'weight').inV()).times(2).path().by().by('weight')```

Comment: I didn't know about the it.path. I think we found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `it.path` property of the loop step is the key. Since the weights are on the edges we need to explicitly traverse them so they will be visible in the path:

```
g.v(1).as("start").outE().inV().loop("start"){it.path.collect{it.weight==null ? 0.0 : it.weight}}.sum()<=0.3f}.dedup()
```

If you want to traverse both in and out edges you'll need to add `simplePath()` to prevent the traversal from circling back on itself.

```
g.v(1).as("start").bothE().bothV().loop("start"){it.path.collect{it.weight==null ? 0.0 : it.weight}}.sum()<=0.3f}.simplePath().dedup()
```

Answer (score 3):

TinkerPop 3 syntax could look like this:

g.withSack(0.0f).V(1).repeat(outE().sack(sum, 'weight').inV()).times(2).sack().path()

which outputs the full path, including the edges, along with the summed weight of the edges:

==>[v[4256], e[178-3a8-1lh-374][4256-onetwo->4144], v[4144], e[16u-374-36d-3a0][4144-twothree->4248], v[4248], 3.0]